# MYSQL Order from another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, tablesorter

I have a question.

I have here 2 tables

table 1 : products

```
product_id , name , images_sideview
```

table 2 : product_descriptions

```
product_id , volgnr
```

I want to sort them with the numbers from Table 2 and  volgnr field.

Is there a way to do this with mysql ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 2 ways to sort. Ascending order and Descending order. You have not mentioned the order. So I am providing you both answers with 2 variations:

**ASCENDING ORDER:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
GROUP BY table1.product_id
ORDER BY table2.product_id ASC, table2.volgnr ASC;
```

**DESCENDING ORDER:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
GROUP BY table1.product_id
ORDER BY table2.product_id DESC, table2.volgnr DESC;
```

If you want to tell MySQL to first sort **FIRST by volgnr and then by product_id**:

**ASCENDING ORDER:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
GROUP BY table1.product_id
ORDER BY table2.volgnr ASC, table2.product_id ASC;
```

**DESCENDING ORDER:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
GROUP BY table1.product_id
ORDER BY table2.volgnr DESC, table2.product_id DESC;
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit 1:**

I have now edited the query so that it does not give you duplicates in results. Try it out and let me know how that goes.

**Edit 2:**
Added Group By clause. Try this out.

Comment: This works to but once again it gives me duplicate products im getting every product three times

Comment: Instead of just SELECT *, use SELECT DISTINCT * and that should solve it.

Comment: I have used SELECT DISTINCT products.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_descriptions ON products.product_id = product_descriptions.product_id
ORDER BY product_descriptions.product_id ASC, product_descriptions.volgnr ASC; 
And it works Great thank you very much @devner

Comment: Glad to hear that. In case the problem repeats in future, use the revised query. I have added Edit 2 and that should fix it for good.

Comment: Thanks man :) im also kinda new to stackoverflow but im already liking it :D

Comment: Is there a reason or inherent benefit to using an inner join as opposed to a left join? Wouldn't doing so eliminate the need for the group by/distinct?

Comment: @Chaosxmk I use INNER JOIN as I want to see only the entries that exists in both the tables. Using LEFT JOIN would bring all values from the LEFT table, regardless of whether it has matching entries in the RIGHT table or not.  IMO, GROUP BY / DISTINCT should not be your criteria for using a specific type of JOIN. You only want to filter your data and hence use GROUP BY / DISTINCT. To answer your question, using INNER, LEFT or RIGHT join only depends upon your needs to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from products t1
inner join product_descriptions t2 on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
order by t2.volgnr
```

Comment: wont the * give an error cause the product_id is in both tables?

Comment: Not sure about MySQL - I imagine the OP will want to select specific columns.

Comment: @trembon No, the * won't cause an error. Referencing just "product_id" would cause an error. Likewise if you had two columns named the same, one in each table, you would only get the results from t2. However, this might return more results than you wanted if there are multiple rows in Table2 for each product_id. You might want to do something like SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id,t1.name FROM... or possibly a GROUP BY with a GROUP_CONCAT if you want the volgnr value.

Comment: @trembon, no, duplicate column names in `SELECT *` don't error. MySQL doesn't need to distinguish between them because you're not doing anything with them.

Comment: I tried your code @RedFilter now i have this:
select *
from products t1
inner join products_descriptions on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
order by t2.volgnr

but it seems not to work. what im a doing wrong ?

Sorry im not so good with MSQL

Comment: What error did you receive? Are you not seeing any records or are you simply receiving errors? Check out my answer below to see if it works out for you.

Comment: @Jeff You are missing the `t2` alias on `products_descriptions`. Try my updated query.

Comment: Instead of just SELECT *, use SELECT DISTINCT * and that should solve it.

Comment: Now i have select DISTINCT *
from products t1
inner join product_descriptions t2 on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
order by t2.volgnr
But still gives me duplicated items

Comment: Can you paste the table schema with the values?

Comment: I have used @Devner solution and that works great. thank you guys for your support really helped me out and i have learned alot once again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.'product_id', p.'name', p.'images_sideview' 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_descriptions d ON p.product_id = d.product_id 
ORDER BY d.volgnr;
```