# Ordering By Another Table Column If Exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm putting together a simple forum script with topics/posts. I'm trying to order topics by latest post and I've had some luck with the answer in the following question: [MYSQL Order from another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788006/mysql-order-from-another-table), but the problem I have is that some topics don't have any posts yet, so the query doesn't select those topics at all.

Current coding is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT forum.* 
FROM forum 
INNER JOIN forum_posts 
      ON forum.id = forum_posts.parent_id 
GROUP BY forum.id 
ORDER BY forum_posts.parent_id DESC, 
         forum_posts.time_created DESC 
LIMIT ?,?
```

I want to tell the ORDER BY to order by forum.time_created if there are no matches in forum_posts.parent_id for a topic.

---

On a side note, I would also like to know how to put a WHERE clause into this query as well. I want to only get rows from forum table "WHERE access <= ?", but can't work out *where* to put that snippet in.

Any help much appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

Target is to return topics (from forum table)
According to following details:

1. WHERE forum.access <= ?
2. LIMIT ?,?
3. ORDER BY
   Latest Post From forum_posts table with forum_posts.parent_id matching on forum.id,
   or forum.time_created

---

**EDIT 2:**

An example SQLfiddle with relevant data. This doesn't work as the order should really come out as 11,10,9,1,2
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83535/2

Comment: You need to combine an OUTER JOIN, i.e. a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN with a GROUPWISE MAX query (the uncorrelated subquery example documented in the manual is usually fastest).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, any help in improving my query code-wise?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be909/1

Here's my final query:

```
SELECT forum.*, recent_forum_posts.time_created as latest_post
FROM forum 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(forum_posts.time_created) as time_created, forum_posts.parent_id
           FROM forum_posts
           GROUP BY forum_posts.parent_id) AS recent_forum_posts
        ON forum.id = recent_forum_posts.parent_id 
WHERE forum.access > 2
ORDER BY recent_forum_posts.time_created IS NULL DESC,
         recent_forum_posts.time_created DESC,
         forum.time_created DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Essentially, the subquery (the bit in brackets after LEFT JOIN) selects the most recent post for each `parent_id` from the `forum_posts` table.

That is then LEFT JOINed (as we want to list all forum's even if there are no posts yet).

Comment: This is close, but the missing point is that if there are no posts the order by should default to the forum.time_created.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b2af/1 - example fiddle where topic 3 should be at top because creation date is latest even though it has no posts.

Comment: On a larger table the performance will be worse, but you can add an extra ORDER BY clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0456f/1 - I'll update my answer too

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm using MySQLi and I'm getting a warning: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

I've checked forum table & bind variables does equal full number of columns from the table. Any reason why this query might be problematic with mysqli prepared statement?

Comment: If you post another question with that code I can have a look, but that's a PHP code issue not a MySQL query issue.

Comment: The query seems to add an extra field to the forum table output when running which wasn't being picked up in the bind_result. Fixed that now. However it still doesn't seem to be working on my system like on the sqlfiddle. I will play around with it some more. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can simplify this query by using `COALESCE()` in the `ORDER BY`.  (I can't guarantee the performance of this though, as it's essentially a `CASE` statement...).  Also should make it select the correct results, given that the current order by is going to group queries by whether or not they have posts, first.  Wasn't there a 'parent group' that needed to be included too?